# Get two lists from a common list

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

If I have the following list:

```
list={{tau -> 32.8775, b -> 0.299216}, {tau -> 24.4891, 
  b -> 0.277134}, {tau -> 12.6688, b -> 0.356032}, {tau -> 4.84722, 
  b -> 0.30632}, {tau -> 0.134423, b -> 0.965791}, {tau -> 0.103983, 
  b -> 0.587649}, {tau -> 0.0610192, b -> 0.999985}};
```

How can I get one list with only the values of the different `tau` and another one with only the values of `b`. For example, for the first list I should get:

`listtau={32.8775,24.4891,12.6688,4.84722,0.134423,0.103983,0.0610192}`

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
listtau = tau /. list
```

> ```
> {32.8775, 24.4891, 12.6688, 4.84722, 0.134423, 0.103983, 0.0610192}
> ```

```
listb = b /. list
```

> ```
> {0.299216, 0.277134, 0.356032, 0.30632, 0.965791, 0.587649, 0.999985}
> ```

Or, both lists in a single step:

```
{listtau, listb} = ReplaceAll[list] /@ {tau, b}
```

> ```
> {{32.8775, 24.4891, 12.6688, 4.84722, 0.134423, 0.103983,  0.0610192}, 
> {0.299216, 0.277134, 0.356032, 0.30632, 0.965791, 0.587649, 0.999985}}
> ```

You can also use

```
Transpose[{tau, b} /. list]

Values[FilterRules[list, #]] & /@ {tau, b} 

GroupBy[Join @@ list, First -> Last] /@ {tau, b}

Lookup[{tau, b}] @ Merge[list, Identity]

Merge[list, Identity] /@ {tau, b}

Values @ Merge[Identity] @ list

Transpose @ Values @ list

Transpose[list /. Rule -> Last]
```

to get the same result.

***Note:*** The last three methods assume that the ordering of the rules `tau -> ..` and `b -> ..` is the same in all sublists.

Comment: I'd say that `Lookup[list, tau]` and `Lookup[list, b]` are the idiomatic ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
First /@ Values[list]
Last /@ Values[list]
```

Comment: `Values /@ list // Thread`

Answer (score 3):

Simplicity of the approach   `tau /. list` and `b /. list` makes it quite natural to exploit. Nevertheless one can take into account another approach which can appear to be more efficient for long lists:

```
listtau = Last @@@ First @ Transpose @ list
listb = Last @@@ Last @ Transpose @ list
```

> ```
> {32.8775, 24.4891, 12.6688, 4.84722, 0.134423, 0.103983, 0.0610192}
> {0.299216, 0.277134, 0.356032, 0.30632, 0.965791, 0.587649, 0.999985}
> ```

It might be reasonable to consider also:

```
list[[All, 1, 2]]
list[[All, 2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{listtau, listb} = Transpose@list[[;; , ;; , 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of more ways to extract `tau` and `b` from `list`

**Method 1**

```
assoc = Association[#] & /@ list;
listTau = #[tau] & /@ assoc
listB = #[b] & /@ assoc
```

**Method 2**

```
listTau = Values[First[#]] & /@ list
listB = Values[Last[#]] & /@ list
```